# how to set connection string in webconfig if application is hosted in Sever(IIS7.0)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity

how to validate, my connection string is valid or not.i am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

**this is my connection string**

```
<add name="severEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.DbSystem.csdl|res://*/App_Code.DbSystem.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.DbSystem.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=abc-san72\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Db_mydata;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

i have created my all table like this structure

```
abc-san72\SQLEXPRESS(SQL SERVER 10.16.1300-DOMAIN\UESR)
|_DATAbASE
    |_Db_mydata
         |_TABLES
```

still i am not able to open my application.i am sure of it that my connection string is not proper.so please let me know to correct this my connection string.and we need ADO.Net Entity Framework 4.1 RC installed on IIS?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: i wanted my connection string as based on like entity framework.